# How to set title position inside graph in scatter plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, position, title, scatter-plot

**MWE:**
I would like the title position same as in the graph :
[image]

Here is my code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random 


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = random.sample(range(256),200)
y = random.sample(range(256),200)

cor=np.corrcoef(x,y)

plt.scatter(x,y, color='b', s=5, marker=".")
#plt.scatter(x,y, label='skitscat', color='b', s=5, marker=".")
ax.set_xlim(0,300)
ax.set_ylim(0,300)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Correlation Coefficient: %f'%cor[0][1])
#plt.legend()
fig.savefig('plot.png', dpi=fig.dpi)
#plt.show()
```

But this gives :
[image]

How do I fix this title position?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

assign two corresponded value to X and Y axis. notice! to have title inside graph, values should be in (0,1) interval. you can see a sample code here:

```
import matplotlib. pyplot as plt
A= [2,1,4,5]; B = [3,2,-2,1]
plt.scatter(A,B)
plt.title("title", x=0.9, y=0.9)
plt.xlabel("x-axis")
plt.ylabel("y-axis")
plt.show()
```

Comment: You should add some sort of explanation so the the readers know what you did and where you did

Comment: I was in hurry, next time I'll, thank you for advise!

Answer (score 4):

It will be unnecessarily complicated to move the `title` at some arbitrary position inside the axes.
Instead one would rather create a `text` at the desired position.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.random.randint(256,size=200)
y = np.random.randint(256,size=200)

cor=np.corrcoef(x,y)

ax.scatter(x,y, color='b', s=5, marker=".")

ax.set_xlim(0,300)
ax.set_ylim(0,300)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.text(0.9, 0.9, 'Correlation Coefficient: %f'%cor[0][1], 
        transform=ax.transAxes, ha="right")

plt.show()
```

[image]